# Django Syntax Error in url.py file

Tags: python, django

I am working through the getting started with django project and keep getting a syntax error at the end of the first video when running locally:

```
SyntaxError at /  
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 12)  
Request Method: GET  
Django Version: 1.5  
Exception Type: SyntaxError  
Exception Value:invalid syntax (urls.py, line 12)
```

My urls.py file is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url  
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.views.generic import TemplateView  

admin.autodiscover()  

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$",TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"))  
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))  
)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you're missing some commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
url(r"^$",TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"))  
# no comma at the end here --------------------------------^
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

Without Python sees `url() url()` side by side without a delimiter.

Corrected code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$",TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))  
)
```

Comment: according to standard Django form, there should also be a comma after the admin line as well

Comment: @MattDMo: that comma is optional, there is statement after it.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to look like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$",TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),  
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))  
)
```

notice the comma at the end of the second line

Answer (score -3):

Have you already created an app using "python manage.py startapp "? If so, you should be able to just replace the TemplateView.as_view.... with ".views." if you have a function to handle the viewing ([view function docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/views/)). Your function would end up looking something like this:

```
def pageIndex(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html")
```

and your urlconf would be

```
url(r"^$","<appname>.views.pageIndex")
```

Comment: This isn't related to the problem he is having, and a very confusing solution (not to mention wrong) for a complete beginner. -1